# Node.js 10 HTTPS server is rejecting connections

Tags: node.js, ssl, curl, https, openssl

I have simple Node.js HTTPS server

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const config = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('cert/server-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert/server-crt.pem'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('cert/ca-crt.pem'),
};

const server = https.createServer(config, ((req, res) => {
  console.log('Got request');

  res.end();
}));

server.listen(3333);
```

I use `curl` on embedded system.

```
# curl -V
curl 7.52.1 (arm-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.52.1 wolfSSL/3.9.8
Protocols: file ftp ftps http https smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IPv6 Largefile SSL UnixSockets
```

When I use Node.js other then version 10 - everything works nicely.

HTTPS server running on **Node.js v8.2.1**

```
# curl -k -v "https://10.43.11.128:3333/"
*   Trying 10.43.11.128...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 10.43.11.128 (10.43.11.128) port 3333 (#0)
* SSL connected
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.43.11.128:3333
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
```

HTTPS server running on **Node.js v10.1.0**

```
# curl -k -v "https://10.43.11.128:3333/"
*   Trying 10.43.11.128...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 10.43.11.128 (10.43.11.128) port 3333 (#0)
* SSL_connect failed with error -313: revcd alert fatal error
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) SSL_connect failed with error -313: revcd alert fatal error
```

What has changed in Node.js 10 with regards to HTTPS? I suspect I'll have to change SSL settings but I am to sure how.

---

UPDATES:

Trying to access HTTP (Node.js v10.1.0)

```
# curl --insecure -v "10.43.11.128:3333/"
*   Trying 10.43.11.128...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 10.43.11.128 (10.43.11.128) port 3333 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.43.11.128:3333
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host 10.43.11.128 left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Wireshark captured [pcap file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uaC6EsfdQDWsdD2r9oWKS4f7M32NtxhT).

Comment: have you tried `Node.js v10.9.0` ?

Comment: @ArifKhan yes and no difference

Comment: most likely your TLS lib is too old and there's some (now hopefully fixed) bug in it causing this. wolfSSL Version 3.9.8 was released in 2016.. try updating curl to a 2018 version of woflSSL, like 3.15.3

Comment: @hanshenrik Thanks, that would be ideal, but it's not possible - device has old FW and readonly filesystem... and even if I upgrade I'd still like to make the Node server work with old devices.

Comment: @m1ch4ls try using an old 2015-2016 version of NodeJS, like https://nodejs.org/download/release/v4.2.4/ , can curl communicate with that?

Comment: Have you tried to execute your ssl connection request from elsewhere other than curl?

Comment: @hanshenrik Old node versions work fine... I've tried couple and everything works except Node 10...

Comment: @m1ch4ls then i'm like 99% sure, it's a bug/problem with your old WolfSSL, update libcurl/WolfSSL and the problem will probably go away.

Answer (score 4):

Problem is that the client is not broadcasting support for a cipher suite or extension that the server requires.

Some common solutions to this problem may be:
- If using ECC, the server requires the Supported Curves Extension to be enabled.  Compile wolfSSL with "--enable-supported curves" to resolve.
- wolfSSL has static key cipher suites disabled by default for security.  Please see note at the top of the README for instructions on re-enabling static-key cipher suites if your server requires them.

[Here is the Thread which discuses the error which you have received](https://www.wolfssl.com/forums/topic839-solved-err-313-revcd-alert-fatal-error.html) . Hope this fixes you issue

Comment: Thanks for the pointer... unfortunately recompilation is not an option. I cannot replace system's `curl`. I have to somehow tweak Node.js SSL/TLS settings instead to support old clients. Security is not a concern because this is only for development and testing.

Comment: Your answer doesn't solve my problem but by so far has given me leads that will hopefully help me to resolve it on my own. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Validate which headers curl sends, you can use the -v argument for that.

> curl -vIX "https://10.43.11.128:3333/"

also 
 In node,

just console.log(req._headers) after req.end() and compare your header to further solve the problem.Also i request to try wireshark (http://www.wireshark.org/) for ssl connection testing.

As it's working by --insecure but you need to know the reason.

**--insecure**

- (SSL) This option explicitly allows curl to  perform  "insecure"
               SSL connections and transfers. All SSL connections are attempted
               to be made secure by using the CA certificate  bundle  installed
               by  default.  This  makes  all connections considered "insecure"
               fail unless -k, --insecure is used.

Also can you please try this

```
const https = require("https"),
  fs = require("fs");

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("/cert/server-key.pem"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("/cert/server-cert.pem")
};

const app = express();

app.use((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
});

app.listen(8000);

https.createServer(options, app).listen(8080);
```

Comment: `curl -k -vIX HEAD "https://10.43.11.128:3333"` gives the same results as in the question... The request never gets to Node server.

Comment: one option can you please try remove -k and run only ---------->curl -vIX "https://10.43.11.128:3333/"

Comment: Does nothing:

# curl -vIX "10.43.11.128:3333/"
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' for more information

Comment: can you once try this also curl --insecure -v "10.43.11.128:3333/"

Comment: Answer updated with `curl` output hitting HTTP and Wireshark capture file.

Comment: I think curl works fine - my guess is that default supported ciphers has changed in Node and I have to change that setting. But I can't figure out which onces... changelog doesn't say much

Comment: please try the use of express as i have updated code in my answer .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179523/discussion-between-this-is-om-vm-and-m1ch4ls).